# Is there a pre-Java-8 functional interface that's a drop in replacement for java.util.function.Consumer<T>?

Tags: java, interface, lambda, java-8

In anticipation of moving to Java 8, I'm trying to write my code in a way that's conducive to using lambdas.

I have a need for a functional interface with a single method that takes one argument of some type `T` and returns `void`.  This is the signature of [`java.util.function.Consumer`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)'s `accept()` method, but of course I can't use that yet.

Is there another interface in the standard Java 7 (and preferably Java 6) API that I can use instead?  I know I can create my own, but esp. until this code is ported to Java 8, it's better for readability if I can use a standard interface that's already familiar from the standard Java 6/7 APIs.

The closest thing I've found so far is [`com.google.common.base.Function<T,Void>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html), but (a) it's not part of the standard Java API and (b) its documentation says "instances of Function are generally expected to be referentially transparent -- no side effects", which is contrary to my intended use (with a `Void` return type).

Comment: You can use lambdas any where there is a functional interface, which is an interface with only one method. If you want to model your code so that it would be easier to use with lambdas, try to use more functional interfaces wherever possible.

Comment: If there was such an interface you knew it. How could an interface being so esoteric that you never heard of it improve the readability compared to a new interface named `Consumer` just like the Java8 one which intention it matches?

Comment: I would just copy paste the code from jdk8's Consumer (removing any Java-8 specific annotations). When you move to Java 8 you just need to replace the anonymous classes by lambdas and remove the imports to your own Consumer class.

Comment: If your own `Consumer`’s single method has the same name and signature as the Java 8 `Consumer` you can make your interface a sub-interface of `Consumer` during the transition phase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create your own interface:

```
public interface Invokable <T>{
    public void invoke(T param);
}
```

Alternatively, as suggested, you could use the same interface as the Java 8 `Consumer`. The source is included in the Java 8 JDK Early Access download, here with all the comments and annotations removed:

```
public interface Consumer<T>{
    void accept(T t)
    default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after)
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to name it `Consumer` and name the method `accept`, and then when Java 8 comes along you can just get rid of yours. (P.S. Your `Invoke` method should be named `invoke`.)

Comment: Thanks for the case fix, I'm too entrenched in C# =(

Comment: @Holger's comment is right on, as illustrated by the obscurity of @jpvee's answer.  :)  It seems that it's best to just clone `Consumer` for now, and replace it with the stock version after updating to Java 8.

Comment: This guy deserves a beer! Thanks for reminding simple java concept.

Answer (score 2):

Ha, found one! Look in the JavaEE 7 API: The interface [`javax.websocket.MessageHandler.Whole`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/MessageHandler.Whole.html) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Since my answer is accused of being too obscure, I should add  that `MessageHandler.Whole` is the only (believe me, I checked!) interface that's part of the JavaSE 7 and JavaEE 7 APIs which is functional, i.e. defines a single method which takes a single generic argument and returns `void` (and doesn't throw checked exceptions). I do agree however, that it's questionable whether using this instead of the `Consumer` interface is a good idea :)